# Unique solution of an ordinary differential equation: x''+bx'+cx=0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a second order differential equation:

(*)   ${x}''+b{x}'+cx=0$; $b$ and $c$ constant.

a) By examining the equivalent first order system

$\begin{matrix}
{x}'=y\\ 
\: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \: \:  {y}'=-cx-by
\end{matrix}$

show that if  $b^{2}-4c> 0$,then (*) has a unique solution $x\left ( t \right )$ for every
initial condition of the form

$x\left ( 0 \right )=u$,  ${x}'\left ( 0 \right )=v$

b) If $b^{2}-4c> 0$, what assumption about $b$ and $c$ ensures that

$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty }x\left ( t \right )=0$

for every solution $x\left ( t \right )$?

A question. If the roots of the characteristic polynomial $p\left ( \lambda  \right )=\lambda ^{2}+b\lambda +c=0$ is a unique real value or complex values, what happens with the uniqueness of the initial value problem?

Thank you for your help in solving the proposed exercise and the question

Comment: set $$x(t)=e^{\lambda t}$$

Comment: What did you do so far? $c$ is square of angular frequency when $b=0$, $b$ is damping term. Standard textbook results are available.